# Sensible Way to Capture Stdout for Later Replay?

Tags: python, stream, mocking, stdout

As part of trying to test a legacy function's 'print to stdout' side-effect, I want to capture stdout for later replay.  I use `mock`.

goals (fulfill as many as possible!)

- stdout still prints where it normally would, but there is an additional recorder
- ideally, this should be 'patched' or only occur in a context

My implementation (below) has patching that seems a bit heavy / gross.  Is there a saner way to do it?  `cStringIO`?  Any better parts of `mock` I can use, rather that my `__getattr__` hack?

```
class StreamCapturing(object):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.captured = []
        self.stream = stream

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        return getattr(self.stream,attr)

    def write(self, data):
        self.captured.append(data)
        self.stream.write(data)


import sys
import mock
with mock.patch('sys.stdout',StreamCapturing(sys.stdout)) as ctx:
    sys.stdout.write('a\n')
    print 'stdout'
    sys.__stdout__.write("the real one\n")
    print sys.stdout.captured
    sys.stdout.flush()

assert getattr(sys.stdout,'captured') is None
```

Comment: why are you defining `__getattr__`? It should be sufficient to pass `write` and `flush` calls to the underlying string. Other than that, the code looks good to me, except that I would use cStringIO rather than appending to an array for saving the output.

Comment: ``__getattr__`` is so all the other method calls will pass on (flush, close, etc).  Using the array was mostly so it's simpler to deal when I want to view the captured data.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to save the previous stdout python does it for you and yes use cStringIO

```
import sys
from cStringIO import StringIO

sys.stdout = captured = StringIO()
print "test string"
# test stuff
captured = captured.getvalue()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print "captured",captured
```

Comment: This approach has some non-ideal bits for my app:  1) it assumes that nobody else is replacing sys.stdout along the way (which in testing situations is not true).  2)  output doesn't 'tee'

Answer (score 0):

You do not need mock in this situation:

```
saved_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = StreamCapturing(saved_stdout)

print "stdout"

captured = "".join(sys.stdout.captured)
sys.stdout=saved_stdout
print "captured: ", captured
```

Comment: mock here is nice for the patch capability.  I was more wondering if any of the ``mock`` constructors would be more elegant than my StreamCapturing class.